# How to set objectName for PopupItem from QML?

Tags: qt, popup, qml

QML [Popup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) and derived controls are creating a `PopupItem` object which is a visual representation of it, but `Popup` itself is parented to the `contentData` of the application window. `objectName` specified for `Popup` is not applied to `PopupItem`. For example, the following application:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Popup Test")

    Button {
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: dummyPopup.open()
    }

    Popup {
        id: dummyPopup
        objectName: "dummyPopup"
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 200
        height: 300
        modal: true
        focus: true
    }
}
```

creates `PopupItem` with empty `objectName`
[image: Empty objectName]

Is there a way to set `objectName` for `PopupItem` from QML?

Comment: have you checked that the object name is still empty at runtime ?

Comment: @Greg Yes, see attached screenshot from `GammaRay`

Comment: I ran your exact QML code and the popup objectName is correctly instantiated (Qt 5.12.13). Is the objectName visible in the "QQuickContentItem" inside your "QQuickPopupItem" ?

Comment: @Greg `QQuickContentItem` has `objectName` but it is different from the one set in the `Popup` it is set to "QQuickPPopupItem". I'm using Qt 5.12.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `objectName` of its `contentItem` upon completion:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Popup Test")

    Button {
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: dummyPopup.open()
    }

    Popup {
        id: dummyPopup
        objectName: "dummyPopup"
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 200
        height: 300
        modal: true
        focus: true

        Component.onCompleted: {
            contentItem.objectName = "foo"
            print(contentItem)
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, if this is for auto tests, I have a [hack in C++](https://github.com/mitchcurtis/slate/blob/bcfc3b12bf4ec81cf58799ec3fe89aab37678d21/tests/shared/testhelper.cpp#L967-L979) that avoids the need to give an `objectName` to the `contentItem`:

```
QObject *TestHelper::findPopupFromTypeName(const QString &typeName) const
{
    QObject *popup = nullptr;
    foreach (QQuickItem *child, overlay->childItems()) {
        if (QString::fromLatin1(child->metaObject()->className()) == "QQuickPopupItem") {
            if (QString::fromLatin1(child->parent()->metaObject()->className()).contains(typeName)) {
                popup = child->parent();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return popup;
}
```

You can then use that function [like this](https://github.com/mitchcurtis/slate/blob/master/tests/auto/tst_app.cpp#L739-L741) in your test:

```
const QObject *newProjectPopup = findPopupFromTypeName("NewProjectPopup");
QVERIFY(newProjectPopup);
QTRY_VERIFY(newProjectPopup->property("opened").toBool());
```

Comment: Thanks you! It does exactly what I need. Yes, this is for auto tests, but the C++ won't work for me as I have several PopupItem's (from Drawers) displayed at the same time

Comment: Oh, are the popups all the same type? E.g. `MyPopup`? If so, then yeah, I guess it won't work. Otherwise it should be OK. Alternatively you could write a function that searches for the popup's `objectName`... can't remember why I didn't do it that way. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `objectName` on the `QQuickPopupItem` rather than the `QQuickContentItem` then I think you need to modify the accepted answer a bit. You can access the PopupItem because it's the parent of the contentItem, so:

```
        Component.onCompleted: {
            contentItem.parent.objectName = "foo"
        }
```